# where is the default scheme configuration in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to learning Hadoop. According to the Document:
**All FS shell commands take path URIs as arguments. The URI format is scheme://authority/path. For HDFS the scheme is hdfs, and for the Local FS the scheme is file. The scheme and authority are optional. If not specified, the default scheme specified in the configuration is used. An HDFS file or directory such as /parent/child can be specified as hdfs://namenodehost/parent/child or simply as /parent/child (given that your configuration is set to point to hdfs://namenodehost).**
i want to kown where is the configuration ?Does it in etc/hadoop directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,
All configuration files for hadoop will be in `etc/hadoop` directory.
`core-site.xml` file to be exact for FS configurations, like

```
<property>       
   <name>fs.default.name</name>       
   <value>hdfs://$namenode.full.hostname:8020</value>  
   <description>Enter your NameNode hostname</description>
</property>
```

Comment: Thank you, in the version `Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.7.0` the property is called `fs.defaultFS`